# Using libFlac with Xcode in Mountain Lion

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've decided to write an simple audio converter in objective-c and cocoa, but i cannot link libFlac C library to my Xcode project. When i'm trying to do this, compiler says:

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

What's more, when i'm trying to compile it via command line tools (just like it is described in readme file), terminal throws:

> ot match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must
>   match) ranlib: for architecture: x86_64 file: .libs/libFLAC.a(float.o)
>   has no symbols make[4]: *** [libFLAC.la] Error 1 make[3]:** 
>   [all-recursive] Error 1 make[2]:  **[all-recursive] Error 1 make[1]:
>   *** [all-recursive] Error 1

And when I changed target architecture to intel 32-bit:

> error: -fobjc-arc is not supported with fragile abi
>   Command >/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang >failed with exit code 1

Can anybody help me ? Maybe somebody knows about better, easier way for decoding FLAC files in objective-c ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
./configure --disable-asm-optimizations && make
```

This will build correctly on OS X.