# Can't compile libFlac 1.0.3 on Mavericks (OS X 10.9.1)

Tags: gcc, osx-mavericks, autotools

I am getting the following error when I try to compile libFlac 1.0.3 on OS X 10.9.1:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/ogg/os_types.h:123:
/usr/local/include/ogg/config_types.h:6:9: error: unknown type name 'uint16_t'
typedef uint16_t ogg_uint16_t;
        ^
/usr/local/include/ogg/config_types.h:8:9: error: unknown type name 'uint32_t'
typedef uint32_t ogg_uint32_t;
        ^
2 errors generated.
make[4]: *** [ogg_decoder_aspect.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have tried the following, both of which have resulted in the same error:

- From this post: 
      [Using libFlac in Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469336/using-libflac-with-xcode-in-mountain-lion)

  */configure --disable-asm-optimizations && make*
- From this libFlac ticket: [#405 "-fgnu89-inline" should not be used when building with clang](http://sourceforge.net/p/flac/bugs/405/)
   I edited the configure.ac file to replace this:

  ```
  if test "x$GCC_MAJOR_VERSION$GCC_MINOR_VERSION" = "x42" ; then
      XIPH_ADD_CFLAGS([-fgnu89-inline])
      fi
  fi
  ```

with this:

```
    if test "x$GCC_MAJOR_VERSION$GCC_MINOR_VERSION" = "x42" ; then
      if $CC --version 2>&1| grep -q clang ; then
         true
       else
            XIPH_ADD_CFLAGS([-fgnu89-inline])
            fi
       fi
    fi
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This is my first post, so I have a dumbish questions - can I attach the file or do I have to post the text of it?

Comment: Thanks. Here's the link to the configure file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9099848

Comment: Also, if you want to download the whole Flac 1.0.3 build file, you can get it here: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/flac.html

Comment: Why 1.0.3 and not 1.3.0?

Comment: OOPS. Yes. 1.3.0. Typo. Sorry!